# When I click on a picturebox I need a circle of random color to appear

Tags: c#, .net, drawing

I need some ideas on where to start to modify this program so that when I click on the `picCanvas` (a picturebox) a circle appears in that location. So far the program draws a concentric circle pattern.

All of the code is below:

```
    private Random randClick;
    private Graphics paper;
    private Brush bbrush;
    private Pen pen;
    private int circleSize = 30;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        randClick = new Random();

        paper = picCanvas.CreateGraphics();

    }

    private void picCanvas_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int x, y;

        x = picCanvas.Height / 2;
        y = picCanvas.Width / 2;

        Color color = Color.FromArgb(randClick.Next(0, 256), randClick.Next(0, 256), randClick.Next(0, 256));
        Pen pen = new Pen(color);
        pen.Width = 3;

        circleSize += 10;
        paper.DrawEllipse(pen, x - circleSize/2, y - circleSize/2, circleSize, circleSize);

    }
```

Comment: What have you tried to solve this problem yourself? Or are you just planning on having us write your program for you through a series of incremental questions?

Comment: no i have tried to solve this problem i am new to this and am willing to learn only wanted advice

Comment: Then you must post the code that you have tried to use to solve the problem. This shows us that you have tried something that is not working. Then we'll be happy to help...

Comment: ok i will bear that in mind havent been a member long sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `MouseClick` even and use `X` and `Y` properties of `MouseEventArgs` to get the point where you clicked.

```
private void picCanvas_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    int x, y;

    x = picCanvas.Height / 2;
    y = picCanvas.Width / 2;

    Color color = Color.FromArgb(randClick.Next(0, 256), randClick.Next(0, 256), randClick.Next(0, 256));
    Pen pen = new Pen(color);
    pen.Width = 3;

    circleSize += 10;
    paper.DrawEllipse(pen, e.X - circleSize / 2, e.Y - circleSize / 2, circleSize, circleSize);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help i originally put the e.X and e.Y in but didn't click on events in the design form and mistyped some data but your idea was the same as mine thanks for making it easier was getting fed up of debugging this one

Answer (score 2):

First thing: you should subscribe to the `MouseClick` event instead of `Click` - this way you'll gain access to mouse position and buttons in provided `MouseEventArgs`.

Second thing: the method you try to achieve may not be persistent - after minimizing and restoring window the `DrawEllipse` won't be called again. You have to add drawing methods to `Paint` event. Example below:

```
Point p = Point.Empty; // stores location of last mouseclick
bool clicked = false;  // is picturebox clicked (if yes - circle should be drawn)

private void pictureBox1_MouseClick( object sender, MouseEventArgs e )
{
    p = e.Location;         // capture mouse click position
    clicked = true;         // notify the circle has to be drawn
    pictureBox1.Refresh();  // force refresh of the control
}
private void pictureBox1_Paint( object sender, PaintEventArgs e )
{
    // if there's a circle to be drawn
    if ( clicked )
    {
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;   // grab graphics object
        g.DrawEllipse( Pens.Yellow, p.X - 4, p.Y - 4, 8, 8 );  // draw ellipse (a small one in this case)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Store the info for the location and color of each circle in a List<> at class level.  In this example, I've used a Tuple, but you can also use a custom Class.  In the Paint() event, you iterate over all the entries in the List and render them:

[image]

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Load += new EventHandler(Form1_Load);
        picCanvas.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(picCanvas_Paint);
        picCanvas.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(picCanvas_MouseDown);
    }

    private int circleSize = 30;
    private Random R = new Random();
    private List<Color> NamedColors = new List<Color>();
    private List<Tuple<Point, Color>> Circles = new List<Tuple<Point, Color>>();

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Color C in System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(Color)).GetStandardValues())
        {
            if (C.IsNamedColor)
            {
                NamedColors.Add(C);
            }
        }
    }

    void picCanvas_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Tuple<Point, Color> circle = new Tuple<Point, Color>(
            new Point(e.X, e.Y), 
            NamedColors[R.Next(NamedColors.Count)]);
        Circles.Add(circle);
        picCanvas.Invalidate();
    }

    void picCanvas_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Tuple<Point, Color> circle in Circles)
        {
            Rectangle rc = new Rectangle(circle.Item1, new Size(1, 1));
            rc.Inflate(circleSize / 2, circleSize / 2);
            using (Pen pen = new Pen(circle.Item2, 3))
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(pen, rc);
            }
        }
    }

}
```